# nhibernate group by order by

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, group-by, sql-order-by

**TASK TABLE:**

```
id AssigneeID Name
1    2        TODO1
2    3        TODO2
3    1        TODO3
```

**ASSIGNEE TABLE:**

```
id Name Status
1  Max  Available
2  Ryan NotAvailable
3  Lisa NotAvailable
```

My **jqgrid** table is like this:

```
Name   Assignee Status
TODO1  Ryan     NotAvailable
TODO2  Lisa     NotAvailable
TODO3  Max      Available
```

I want to sort the Status column so i did this:

```
var query = scope.Session.QueryOver<Task>().Where(s=>s.Id!=null);

var x = query.Select(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Property<Task>(task => task.AssigneeID))).AddSortExpression("Status desc").List<Assignee>();
```

however, this returns an error because Status is on the Assignee table, not in the Task table.

moreover, how can i use GROUP BY in my code because i think it will cause an error once i try to sort Status. it will not know which to put first, the NotAvailable of Ryan or the NOt Available of Lisa... please help...

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to make NH aware of the association between task and assignee. Then why do you need a groupBy

```
class Task
{
    public virtual Assignee Assignee { get; set; }
}
```

if you need only these 3 properties

```
SomeDto dto = null;
Assignee assignee = null;
session.QueryOver<Task>()
    .JoinAlias(task => task.Assignee, () => assignee)
    .OrderBy(() => assignee.Status)
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(task => task.Name).WithAlias(() => dto.Name)
        .Select(() => assignee.Name).WithAlias(() => dto.Assignee)
        .Select(task => assignee.Status).WithAlias(() => dto.Status))
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<SomeDto>())
    .List<SomeDto>()
```

or if you want the whole task and assignee objects returned

```
Assignee assignee = null;
var tasks = session.QueryOver<Task>()
    .JoinAlias(task => task.Assignee, () => assignee)
    .OrderBy(() => assignee.Status)
    .List();
```